# Tomcat servlets issue on RedHat Enterprise 5

Tags: xml, apache, tomcat, servlets, redhat

I have recently finished (almost) an application for a contract I was working on, and am porting the current instance from my work computer to the production server to work out any kinks before I do the final steps in dev, and I am running into some configuration problems. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

I was about to ssh into work and check os version, and someone turned it off apparently... I think it is running either Natty or Oneiric. The production server is running Redhat Enterprise 5.

My web application on my destkop (Ubuntu) is hosted with apache2. It is one web page with a proxy that routes traffic to a tomcat6 instance on the same computer via AJP. This proxy is only hit by AJAX requests initiated from the web page.

The Red Hat instance I am porting this application to had tomcat already installed. RELEASE-NOTES indicates that it is version 7.0.23. Before I dropped in my webapp, I wanted to test the functionality of the tomcat in place. I made a dummy webapp folder in webapps/ and an index.html file within, and attempted to connect through a web-browser with no success.

Starting tomcat yields the following loggings:

```
Apr 19, 2013 5:38:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-\
1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.41.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.41.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.41.x86_64/jre/../lib/amd64:/\
usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Apr 19, 2013 5:38:22 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
Apr 19, 2013 5:38:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 19, 2013 5:38:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 19, 2013 5:38:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1364 ms
Apr 19, 2013 5:38:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 19, 2013 5:38:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
Apr 19, 2013 5:38:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardCo\ntext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/dell/oma/common/OMASessionListener : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.dell.oma.com\mon.OMASessionListener)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2827)             at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1655)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
```

...
and some other lines that are very similar failures (child containers).

And here is my $TOMCAT/conf/server.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

<GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>

<Service name="Catalina">
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>

<Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context debug="0" docBase="omsa" path="">
                    <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager" saveOnRestart="false"/>
            </Context>
    </Host>
</Engine>
</Service>
</Server>
```

I am still kind of new to servlet and xml configurations. If I left out any necessary information, let me know and I will post edits. Thanks everyone for your help. This has been troubling me for a day or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java class version 51.0 is from java 7. This means this dell library is compiled for java 7, while your server is running java-1.6.0.41. So you either have to upgrade the java version on your server or recompile the dell library. First approach seems to be preferable as java 6 isn't supported any more since Feburary.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Indeed I did not have java 7 selected as the default jdk/jre on the server. I tried that, but am still getting lots of error messages. Since this post, I gave up on that tomcat instance, installed my own on the side, and am using that. Don't know who ruined the other one, but it is pretty messed up. Thanks for your response!